# recursion : from Prolog to SWRL

Tags: prolog, swrl

Do you know how to translate recursion in SWRL. For example, this type of Prolog rules : (an ancestor is a parent or an ancestor of a parent.

```
ancestor(X,Y):- parent (X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):- parent(X,Z), ancestor(Z,Y).
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence, SWRL is [Datalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog#Example). Just reverse heads and bodies:

```
hasParent(?x, ?y) -> hasAncestor(?x, ?y)
hasAncestor(?y, ?z) ^ hasParent(?x, ?y) -> hasAncestor(?x, ?z)
```

---

SWRLTab in Protégé:

[image: swrltab]

Initial assertions:

[image: asserted]

Inferred (via Pellet) assertions:

[image: inferred]

Of course, pure OWL solution also exists.